# How do I reference a String resource in a class name and concatenate it with another string in XML?

Tags: android, xml

I have created a String resource in Android:

```
<string name="package_Name">com.blue.MonkeyTech</string>
```

I want to reference this in a view element in XML
Here is what I got so far:

```
<view class="@string/package_Name"+".AppHome$DewiButton"
```

I want to reference the package name from the string resource and then concatenate the class name "AppHome" along with the inner class "DewiButton"
This just gives me an error
How do I solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible.  If you give details of what you're trying to achieve then maybe someone can help you with a workaround

Comment: sometimes I change the package name of the project. I want to store the package name once, then reference it where needed. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible.  In tools like eclipse you can use the refactor tools which will do most of the work for you - it won't change your manifest file though, or your layout but you can then do a find and replace.